# How to make apache in debian access the resource on the window's ntfs filesystem?

Tags: debian, mount, apache-httpd

The disk partition `sda4` is a ntfs disk.

```
sudo blkid |grep sda4
/dev/sda4: UUID="0042E54842E54350" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="70f5093c-b320-4325-88bb-97748f522332"
```

I mount it automatically when booting.

```
cat /etc/fstab
UUID=0042E54842E54350  /media/debian/0042E54842E54350      ntfs-3g   rw,user,exec,umask=000 0 0
```

Now create a web project `mydoc` on `/media/debian/0042E54842E54350`,set ownership and file's mode:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data  /media/debian/0042E54842E54350/mydoc
sudo chmod  755 -R /media/debian/0042E54842E54350/mydoc
```

Write all the setting such as below:

```
cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName localhost
 DocumentRoot  /media/debian/0042E54842E54350/mydoc 
 Alias  /regular  "/media/debian/0042E54842E54350/mydoc/build/html"
 <Directory /media/debian/0042E54842E54350/mydoc>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

To restart apache service :

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Type `127.0.0.1/regular` in browser.

It encounter error info:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80
```

Check its log:

```
sudo cat /var/log/apache2/error.log
[Thu Aug 06 20:13:41.467015 2020] [core:error] [pid 4248] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:53024] AH00035: access to /favicon.ico denied (filesystem path '/media/debian/0042E54842E54350') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path, referer: http://127.0.0.1/regular/os
```

How to make apache access the resource on the other disk mounted ?
More info:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data  /media/debian/0042E54842E54350/mydoc
```

No error info.

### responses to comments and answers

```
$ ls -ld /media{,/debian{,/0042E54842E54350{,/mydoc}}}
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 Feb  1  2020 /media
drwxr-x---+ 4 root root  4096 Aug  6 21:50 /media/debian
drwxrwxrwx  1 root root 16384 Aug  6 07:55 /media/debian/0042E54842E54350
drwxrwxrwx  1 root root  4096 Aug  6 06:53 /media/debian/0042E54842E54350/mydoc
```

Why can't change the owner for `/media/debian/0042E54842E54350/mydoc`?

```
getfacl  -p "/media/debian"
# file: /media/debian
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:debian:r-x
group::---
mask::r-x
other::---
```

The real problem is that my pc is dual os (win10+debian),i want build a web app on some disk partition which it can be used both by win10 and debian,is it feasible?
If i set the web app on ntfs,apache can work on win10,when i reboot to switch to debian, apache on debian can't read and write it.
If i set the web app on one of ext2/ext3/ext4 ,apache can work on debian, when i reboot to switch to win10, apache on win10 can't read and write it.
Is there no way to achieve my target?

Comment: Note: after the reboot, your permissions could be lost (not all filesystems supports group permission. your umask is also extreme. In addition, you should check the order. You have also `user` in fstable, so it is not default mounted. Apache could start yearly. I recommend you to make apache see one "dir" in your home, but makes iy a symlink, so apache is happy, and you do not need hard mounting order (and you can umount and remount without need to restart apache)

Comment: Restart apache ,not reboot os.

Comment: Add the output of `ls -ld /media{,/debian{,/0042E54842E54350{,/mydoc}}}` to your question.

Comment: OK, there's ACL on `/media/debian` so we also need the output of `getfacl /media/debian`.

Comment: You are looking for a "reputable source" for how file permissions work? I suggest `man 5 acl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The problem with chown

You can't use `chown` because the NTFS-3G driver does not yet know which NTFS Security IDs (SIDs for short) correspond to Linux UID/GID numbers and vice versa.

In the metadata of a NTFS filesystem, the owner of the file and any other users/groups are specified by Security IDs, which are long strings. Unix-style UIDs/GIDs (used in the metadata of Unix-style filesystems) are simple integer numbers. Writing an Unix-style UID or GID into e.g. the "file owner" field in the NTFS metadata would be interpreted as "corrupted metadata" by Windows and any other NTFS driver that expects well-formed NTFS metadata.

To fix that, you will need to generate a `UserMapping` file that defines supported Linux UID/GID numbers and their corresponding NTFS SIDs.

The NTFS-3G driver provides a tool to help you create such a file. The author of the driver simply named it `usermap`, which might lead to conflicts with other tools; in some distributions it seems to be named [`ntfs-3g.usermap`](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-ntfs-3g.usermap/), but specifically in Debian, you will find it by name `ntfsusermap`.

You could also use a [Windows version of the usermap tool](http://jp-andre.pagesperso-orange.fr/tools.zip): just extract the `usermap.exe` from the .ZIP package, and run it in Windows command prompt, and have it list all the SIDs used on the drive with the corresponding Windows user/group names. You can then open it in a text editor, replace the Windows user/group names with Linux user/group names you want to treat as their equivalents, and then save the resulting file as `/media/debian/0042E54842E54350/.NTFS-3G/UserMapping` (as viewed from Linux).

With a Linux version of the usermap tool, the procedure is much the same; however, you will need to identify the user and group SIDs yourself based on file names, as the Linux version of the tool has no access to the Windows user database. Instead, it will show you some example files and ask you to identify the name of the user or group those files would belong to, which can be tedious sometimes.

You can find more detailed instructions on the use of the usermap tool [in the webpage of Tuxera](https://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/user-mapping/), who make an advanced version of the NTFS-3G driver for use on Macs, and seem to be the current maintainer of the [open-source NTFS-3G driver.](https://www.tuxera.com/community/open-source-ntfs-3g/) That's about as authoritative source as you can get!

Once you've placed the `UserMapping` file in the proper position, simply unmount & re-mount the NTFS partition, and then `chown` and `chgrp` will start working on the NTFS filesystem. However, they will still only work for users/groups for which there is a configured mapping between the Linux UID/GID and the corresponding Windows SID.

### The other problem

As mentioned by Hauke Laging, your `/media/debian/` directory has an ACL that prevents any user other than `debian` (including the `www-data` user of Apache) from accessing anything within that directory tree. This is probably because `/media/debian/` is used by the `udisksd` daemon to allow the GUI desktop tools of locally-logged-in `debian` user to mount removable media within that specific directory tree without root permissions.

I would recommend that you mount the NTFS filesystem into some other location that is not under `/media/debian`, to avoid that ACL. The `udisksd` will probably enforce that ACL on any `/media/<username>` directory when the corresponding user logs in, so you should make your own custom mount point for this filesystem, as it is clearly supposed to be accessible whether or not the `debian` user is logged in.

For example, you might create a `/media/docdrive` directory, then change your `/etc/fstab` line into:

```
UUID=0042E54842E54350  /media/docdrive      ntfs-3g   rw,defaults,windows_names 0 0
```

(See `man mount.ntfs-3g` for the meanings of the mount options; when using the UserMapping file, you should not need the `user,exec,umask=000` options any more, and they would in fact block you from using `chmod` on the filesystem.)

...and then change the `Alias` line in your Apache configuration to:

```
Alias  /regular  "/media/docdrive/mydoc/build/html"
```

Answer (score 1):

### non-Linux filesystems

`chown`, `chmod`, `setfacl` and so on work on Linux filesystems only. The very reason is that you must be able to store that information in that filesystem. Usually that is not possible or at least not feasible.

Thus for such filesystems the user and group and permissions which are shown to Linux are determined at mount time. As you can configure `umask` in `/etc/fstab` you can also configure the user and group to be used.

### the real problem

The real problem is the permissions of `/media/debian`, not related at all to the NTFS mount. The only ones which can access that directory are the user `root` and the members of the group `debian`.

Comment: @A.B Is there someting wrong with the site? The content of the comment is what I expected but usually questions about the question situation are answered by the questioner...

Answer (score 0):

Make a prepare for mounting:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/winntfs
sudo mkdir /mnt/winntfs/.NTFS-3G
```

Create UserMapping

```
sudo ntfsusermap  /dev/sda4
```

imput www-data for user
input www-data for group

Now you'll get the content such as following:

```
sudo cat  UserMapping
# Generated by ntfsusermap for Linux, v 1.2.0
:www-data:S-1-5-21-2378563617-2567501716-2196283026-513
www-data:www-data:S-1-5-21-2378563617-2567501716-2196283026-1001
```

Copy it for using:

```
sudo cp UserMapping  /mnt/winntfs/.NTFS-3G/UserMapping
```

Set ownership and file mode.

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data  /mnt/winntfs/mydoc
sudo chmod  755 -R /mnt/winntfs/mydoc
```

Set apache2 configuration on debian.

```
sudo vim  /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName localhost
 DocumentRoot  /mnt/winntfs/mydoc 
 Alias  /regular  "/mnt/winntfs/mydoc/build/html"
 <Directory /mnt/winntfs/mydoc>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Set fstab for mounting.

```
sudo vim /etc/fstab
UUID=0042E54842E54350  /mnt/      ntfs-3g   rw,defaults  0 0
```

Restart it and type `127.0.0.1` for reading your web app.

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```